# SpringBoot+Neo4J OGM update record

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am getting very weird problem when trying to update the record in database .**Main Node is updating properly but Relationship not creating after deleting it.**

I have Node with relationship in database i am trying to update it via this code

```
Role roleRecord = findByUuid(uuid);//Get Role Record
Role roleData = new Role();//Create a new role object and update values
roleData.setDescription(role.getDescription());
roleData.setUuid(roleRecord.getUuid());
roleData.setRoleName(roleRecord.getRoleName());
roleData.setLabels(updatedLabelRecord);
deleteRole(roleRecord);// Delete existing role from database
for (Labels label : dbRecord) { //Delete relationship Node
    deleteLabel(label);
}
createRole(roleData);// Then Create role and Label with new Data set
```

This code creating `Role` record but not the `Label` Node(Which is a relationship),Relationship something like this

```
Role->FILTERS_ON->Label
```

**EDIT 1-**

Role is a Neo4j Entity

deleteRole is method

```
public void deleteRole(Role roleEntity) {
        roleRepository.delete(roleEntity);
    }
```

deleteLabel is a method

```
public void deleteLabel(com.nokia.nsw.uiv.uam.entities.Labels label) {
        labelRepository.delete(label);

    }
```

createRole is a method

```
public Role createRole(Role role) {
        return roleRepository.save(role);
    }
```

**EDIT 2 -**
Role Entity Class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
@Api(
    tags = "Role",
    description = ""
)

@NodeEntity(label = "com.model.Role")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8010543109475083169L;

    private String roleName = null;

    private String description = null;

//  @Relationship(type = "HAS_ROLE", direction="INCOMING")
//  private Tenant tenant;

    @Relationship(type = "FILTERS_ON")
    private List<Labels> labels = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UivUuidStrategy.class)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String uuid;

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

//  public Tenant getTenant() {
//      return tenant;
//  }
//
//  public void setTenant(Tenant tenant) {
//      this.tenant = tenant;
//  }

    public List<Labels> getLabels() {
        return labels;
    }

    public void setLabels(List<Labels> labels) {
        this.labels = labels;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Label Entity class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Properties;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@NodeEntity(label = "com.model.role.Filter")
public class Labels implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String labelName;

    @Properties
    private Map<String, String> match;

    private String access;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UivUuidStrategy.class)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String uuid;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMatch() {
        return match;
    }

    public void setMatch(Map<String, String> match) {
        this.match = match;
    }

    public String getLabelName() {
        return labelName;
    }

    public void setLabelName(String labelName) {
        this.labelName = labelName;
    }

    public String getAccess() {
        return access;
    }

    public void setAccess(String access) {
        this.access = access;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "labelName : " + this.labelName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof Labels) && this.labelName.equals(((Labels) obj).getLabelName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(labelName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you do all the operations within one transaction?

Comment: Yes it's under single transaction

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more in your question what exactly `role`  and what the content of `deleteRole`, `deleteLabel` and `createRole`? Also an excerpt how a `Role` and a `Label` is defined in your application would be really helpful.

Comment: @meistermeier done the changes

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but can you provide the classes `Role` and `Label` or at least an excerpt of it to see how you defined the relationships?
In general it is not a good approach to have a repository for every entity. If `Role` is your aggregate root / "leading" entity, every operation like save, delete etc. should go through its repository by saving the entity after the modifications.

Comment: Due to festival season in India i am also very busy so not able to update the question ,but now added Entity class.